# Issue while creating spring boot maven application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am creating a Rest based web service using spring boot,while deploying in tomcat am not getting error.But when i'm trying to hit the RestController's method which is annotated with `@RequestMapping`  and trying to print a string in the browser.

**Am getting the error:**

type Exception report

> message Circular view path [error]: would dispatch back to the current
>   handler URL [/services-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/error] again. Check your
>   ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified
>   view, due to default view name generation.)

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [error]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/services-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/error] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.prepareForRendering(InternalResourceView.java:205)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:145)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1228)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1011)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:955)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:857)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:291)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration$MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java:90)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:101)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.forwardToErrorPage(ErrorPageFilter.java:173)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:156)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:59)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:101)
```

I am not able to figure out this issues :(

Any help in this regard will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your controller class marked with @RestController. If not, and you just annotated it with @Controller, you have to change the @Controller annotation to @RestController. You can have same result by adding @ResponseBody to your controller class or every controller mothods that is used for restful API.

Comment: My controller is annotated with @RestController. When i'm running main method of boot application , it's giving other issue:

Comment: Oh! this error occured during the spring handle some controller's exception. I missed it. I'm sorry. Please, show me your Spring MVC exception handling and view resolver  configuration.

Comment: In Controller:@RequestMapping(value = "profile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public Profile profile()
 {
  System.out.println("Test Controller");
  
  Profile profile=new Profile();
  profile.setAccountType(123);
  profile.setCardCity("KA");
  return profile;
 }

Comment: This code is not for exception handling nor view resolver. Could you show me your whole spring bean definition file?